# Synchronize "purple links"

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to synchronize the highlighting of all the links that I've clicked across all Google Chrome installations. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: What setting do you have checked for your sync?

Comment: I have checked "sync everything".

Comment: Hmm, then it should be working...

Comment: It's not working right now, and all of my Chrome extensions have stopped working across all of my computers for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't confirm at this time, but try setting up google sync in the settings. This should keep your history in sync between your Chrome installations, and the links are colored (made purple) based upon your history.

Comment: After re-setting my Google Chrome installation and signing in again, I noticed that none of the link highlighting was preserved.

Comment: I've set up sync, and it still doesn't appear to be working - why is this?

Comment: @AndersonGreen I can't explicitly say; Double-check that you're still signed into sync on both computers. I've been using it for the past few months and it's been working well.

Answer (score 0):

Once we activated the Google Sync, all of our browsing history will be maintained and synced across all chrome browser using devices. This includes bookmarks, extensions passwords etc. So all your visited links will be in purple only.

Comment: I noticed that all of the link highlighting was reset after I re-installed Google Chrome. The link highlighting doesn't seem to be saved (but this is possibly because of a bug that I encountered, which also kept the extensions from working properly.)